# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Found below error in my program:

> Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: ''

**Model Class**:

```
import java.util.Date;

private Date dob;
```

**DaoImpl Class**:

```
String dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(sm.getDob());
Date dob = Date.valueOf(dt);
ps.setDate(5, dob);
```

**Main Controller Class**:

```
sm.setDob(dob.getDate());
```

Comment: Once you don't use the java 8 date-api, you should then use the GregorianCalendar class, so you set the date easily.

Comment: But @AdemirConstantino (1) you certainly should prefer to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API that you are referring to (2) the long outdated `GregorianCalendar` class is of no help here.

Answer (score 2):

`preparedStatement` accept `java.sql.Date`:

```
Date dob = Date.valueOf(dt);   
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(dob.getTime());
ps.setDate(5, sqlDate );
```

Comment: Even better, `preparedStatement` accepts a `LocalDate`, the class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API: `ps.setObject(5, yourLocalDate);`. Both `Date` classes are long outdated (no pun intended).